# Clearing file input box in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have an file upload box and a clear button on my page. When I press the clear button, I want the text in the file upload box to be cleared.

The following works in Firefox, but doesn't in IE (the text stays there). Is there a workaround for this?

```
$("#clear").click( function() {
    $("#attachment").val("");
    //document.myform.attachment.value = "";
})
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" />
</form>
<br /><button id="clear">Clear Attachment</button>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VnU4q/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's readonly in [IE8 onwards](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx), so you can't clear it. The simplest way around this security feature is to replace the element with a copy.

**Edit** Found a previous answer to this that suggests the same approach! [Clearing <input type='file' /> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery/1043969#1043969)

Answer (score 18):

One solution I've found is simply doing:

```
document.getElementById('myUploadField').parentNode.innerHTML = document.getElementById('myUploadField').parentNode.innerHTML;
```

Seems like it shouldn't work, but it does.

Comment: Awsome. Thnx a bunch.

Comment: This works... but *why* it works? It seems you're setting a value with the *same* value. Can you please explain the trick?

Answer (score 13):

This solution is more elegant than cloning the input element. You wrap a `<form>` around the element, call reset on the form, then remove the form using unwrap(). Unlike the clone() solutions above, you end up with the same element at the end (including custom properties that were set on it).

Tested and working in Opera, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and IE6+. Also works on other types of form elements, with the exception of type="hidden".

http://jsfiddle.net/rPaZQ/

```
function reset(e) {
  e.wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
  e.unwrap();
}​
```

Comment: Extremely useful if you don't want to do a full reset.

Comment: Not a foolproof solution. Value may be cleared off the input field on UI but can still be accessible from $("#myFileUpload").val()

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```js
 $("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));
```

Answer (score 2):

use simple javascript:

```
formname.reset();
```

See the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/YEeGR/

Comment: Bit of a problem when there are multiple fields on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below method to clear the input file.

### Include this script:

```
 <script>
 function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
 document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML =
    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

### Change HTML to this:

```
<div id="uploadFile_div">
<input type="file" class="fieldMoz" id="uploadFile" onkeydown="return false;" size="40" name="uploadFile"/>
</div>
<a onclick="clearFileInputField('uploadFile_div')" href="javascript:noAction();">Clear</a>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the old-fashioned `<input type="reset" value="clear this">`

Comment: Won't that reset the entire form though? I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: The example you gave only has one element so I thought that would be fine.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion. I suppose in theory I could just save the values of the other form elements and reload them afterwards. :P

Comment: @tskuzzy: If there are multiple file fields in the form, you cannot reload them afterwards.