# How to cancel file upload html?

Tags: html, input

I am using an `input` element with `type="file"`
and I want to cancel selection of something I choose.

I tried using

```
document.getElementById("pic1").value="";
document.getElementById("pic1").src="";
```

But it works only on Firefox.

Does anyone has a solution that works in IE and Chrome?
Please no JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/pywgc/)

- Google Chrome 29

JavaScript:

```
$("#cancel").click(function(){
 document.getElementById("test").value = "";   
})
```

Here is a similar question: [Clearing file input box in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987452/clearing-file-input-box-in-internet-explorer)

> It's readonly in IE8 onwards, so you can't clear it. The simplest way
>   around this security feature is to replace the element with a copy.

And here is a dirty solution to your problem [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/pywgc/1/) from the same question:

JavaScript:

```
$("#cancel").click(function () {
    document.getElementById('test').parentNode.innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').parentNode.innerHTML;
})
```

It's dirty because it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Markasoftware I'm not using jQuery for input clearing. I'm using it for a different button to execute.

Comment: you should use onclick is what i mean

Comment: @Markasoftware I'm more worried if the OP will even reply after this solves his/hers problem. :D

Comment: hey thanks for helping, it's not working ..mabye i need to include any jquery? instead of clean the selection it send the form

Comment: @user2708548 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery/1043969#1043969 here you go some jquery.